# Footer still reflects Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, footer, mso-mse-split

The universal footer on all sites is still reflecting "Meta Stack Overflow".

[image: link with tooltip]

[image: address of link]

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching was at fault.

Fixed now.

Comment: If you're in working from the UK right now, props on being awake!

Comment: @StevenV - heh. Been main dev on the split project, so didn't feel right to not be around when it was going down